# Stopping node server that listening to specific port

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs, gulp

Is it possible to stop express server that's listening to a specific port on the same machine? From a different script? Not the same script.

Let's say I start server in one terminal window by either directly calling node executable and passing the script, or via Grunt/Gulp task.

Now, is it possible to kill the same server by running another Grunt/Gulp task in a different terminal window?

Comment: What operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to have a path that causes the server to exit.  This isn't too secure (you *can* lock it down, but the mere existence of such a path is a liability).  I'd never recommend such a thing for anything facing the real world, but it can suffice for local `grunt` tasks or development.

```
app.get('/thisShouldBeLongAndComplicated', function() { process.exit(); });
```

Then send a request in your other task (using [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request))

```
request.get('localhost:3000/thisShouldBeLongAndComplicated');
```

Comment: oh perfect! I can set the route only for NODE_ENV === 'development" and use it.. thanks